# How to access APIs of a module from another module (Backbone Marionette)

Tags: api, module, code-reuse, marionette, infrastructure

this is my first attempt at using marionette and I have design the application infrastructure of my app as seen below.

Essentially, the idea was to have a 'Answers' module that can be reused in multiple places i.e. Feed Module, Profile Module etc

[image]

Example of what the Answers Module will somewhat look like:

```
@MyApp.module "AnswersModule", (MusesModule, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  class AnswersModule.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      "answers" : "listAnswers"

  API =
    listAnswers: ->
      //Method will fetch a list of muses and populate a view template
      AnswersModule.List.Controller.listAnswers()

  App.addInitializer ->
    new AnswersModule.Router
      controller: API
```

Question:

1) Is this design inline with best practice in using marionette?

2) Can I/Should I be able to access the 'listAnswers' method in the AnswersModule directly from other modules e.g. Feed Module? And how should I go about doing that?

3) For each module that requires embedding of AnswersModule in their own layouts, a different URL is required for fetching a different list of answers i.e. feed has own url for answers fetch, profile has it's own URL for answers. How do I request for a different list via the Answers Module?

I am rather new to marionette and would really like to get the idea and concepts right before proceeding. Any advise on the above would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: was my answer helpful for you? Let me know if I can improve it

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid directly calling into another module. Marionette includes [this library](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr) which is very useful.

You modules should be interacting through events, commands and request/response. This will decouple your modules and make your application more modular.

so your other modules would do something like this:

```
API =
  someMethod: ->
  App.commands.execute('list-answers', { url: 'amazing-answers' })
```

then your AnswersModule would have set it self up to respond to that command and do what it needs to do.

See [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0o2whtCJw8I) for a good overview.